# Making small icon clearer

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It's not really a bug but the ring on the small icon (for example next to a Hot Network Question) is very hard to see. I think it might be worth having a bit of a black border around the ring or darkening it for the smaller versions just to give it a more easily recognizable silhouette

Answer (score 1):

We've darkened the halo a bit in the regular version of the site and added a bit of red to the meta version.

Comment: Grumble grumble, I'd like the rings to extend out farther, but the limits of 16x16 pixels...  Oh well.